# Should there be punctuation before "and" in this sentence?

Tags: commas, conjunctions

Perhaps this is a better sample:

> J, says, **“No!” and Page** furrows her **forehead, and walks** with J to the other side of the room.

Would either of these be better?

> J, says, **“No!” Page** furrows her forehead, and walks with J to the other side of the room.
>
> J, says, “No!” and Page furrows her **forehead. She walks** with J to the other side of the room.

Comment: You don't need commas: J says "No!" Page furrows her forehead and walks with J to the other side of the room.

Answer (score 1):

Two of the commas are unnecessary.

> J says, “No!” Page furrows her forehead and walks with J to the
>   other side of the room.

Answer (score 0):

In *J, says, “No!” Page furrows her forehead, and walks with J to the other side of the room.* the first comma incorrectly separates subject and verb. The comma after *forehead* incorrectly separates the two predicates that follow the one subject (Page). The *and walks* is dependent. If you had a subject there, the comma before *and* would be needed to mark the coordinating conjunction between the two independent clauses. 
Jeff F.'s suggested revision separates the two independent clauses and makes for better reading: J says, “No!” Page furrows her forehead and walks with J to the other side of the room.
KCH incorrectly leaves out the comma needed before J's statement.